# Why does a thread test a condition/property while holding the lock rather than before acquiring the lock?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

From The Arts of Multiprocessing Programming by Herlihy:

> Suppose a thread
>   wants to wait until a certain property holds. **The thread tests the property while
>   holding the lock.** If the property does not hold, then the thread calls await() to
>   release the lock and sleep until it is awakened by another thread.
>
> ```
> 1 Condition condition = mutex.newCondition();
> 2 ...
> 3 mutex.lock()
> 4 try {
> 5     while (!property) { // not happy
> 6         condition.await(); // wait for property
> 7     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
> 8         ... // application-dependent response
> 9     }
> 10    ... // happy: property must hold
> 11 }
> ```
>
> Figure 8.2 How to use Condition objects.

Why does the thread call `mutex.lock()`   before it tests the property (if the property doesn't hold, the thread calls `await()`) rather than after?

Thanks.

Comment: Because the property can change between checking and locking.

Answer (score 1):

If you changed this to:

```
while (!property) {
   mutex.lock();
   condition.await();
   mutex.unlock();
```

The biggest issue would be if the value for property changed between the line

```
while (!property) {
```

and the line

```
   mutex.lock();
```

Then you would be waiting for the property to change when it already was in a passing state.

If you assume you can only change property while holding the lock on the mutex then for the example in your question, you can't call

```
   condition.await();
```

while the property is in the passing state.

To elaborate on this assumption, the example code from the question would usually go hand in hand with some way to set the value of property.  This may be along the lines of

```
void setProperty(boolean newproperty) {
    mutex.lock();
    property = newproperty;
    condition.signalAll();
    mutex.unlock();
}
```

Without this second part you can never guarentee that you only call

```
condition.await();
```

while property is false.

Comment: Thanks. Why do "you assume you can only change property while holding the lock on the mutex then for the example in your question"?

Comment: Because if you could change property without holding the lock on the mutex then you can never guarantee that it wont be changed on another thread between checking it and calling await.

Answer (score 0):

One thing acquiring the lock does is to create a memory barrier, so that the condition isn't checked using cached values that may have gone stale.

Also acquiring the lock ensures that the values checked are not being changed concurrently by some other thread. Otherwise the thread could test the condition and proceed to acquire the lock, then find the condition changed by the time it could acquire the lock. The thread will end up needing to check with the lock held anyway.

The Thread wants to ascertain the state of the locked object, then modify that state while guaranteeing that that state does not change out from under it due to interference by another thread. That means it has to hold the lock across checking and acting. The thread waits after an unsuccessful check (releasing the lock until signaled), then acquires the lock before the next check. Once a check succeeds then it holds the lock until it can finish performing its action on the locked object.

The action performed on the locked object may make sense only if the check is successful (like adding to a bounded buffer). Or the action may involve multiple changes where all the changes need to be applied together (if the locked object has a data structure that is not designed for concurrent access, like ArrayList, that data structure takes multiple steps to add an element, and interference can corrupt the data structure).